Stacking paired columns in R; adding partial names as labels
I am working with a dataset and preparing the variables for HLM. I have six separate columns representing pre- and posttest data. See the example below:
 > head(exdat)
   sub_id mtt_score vat_score time    concept cond day PreCon PreMcq PreFR PostCon PostMcq PostFR
 1      1         9        26    1     cornea C    1      0      1     0       2       1      3
 2      1         9        26    2    thyroid S    1      1      0     1       2       0      0
 3      1         9        26    3      cilia G    2      0      0     0       1       0      0
 4      1         9        26    4    histone C    1      0      0     0       1       0      0
 5      1         9        26    5 epithelium G    1      0      0     0       1       0      0
 6      1         9        26    6       iris S    1      4      1     1       3       1      3

For the above, I'd like to "stack" the columns with matching suffixes: "-Con", "-Mcq", and "-FR" and add an additional column where "Pre" and "Post" are labeled as an additional variable.
I'd like the stacking "interpolated" so Pre is stacked on top of Post for all three: Con, Mcq, Fr, which become three new columns. All other variables should just repeat.
I tried this:
datl <- pivot_longer(
  dat, 
  cols = c(PreCon, PreMcq, PreFR, PostCon, PostMcq, PostFR), 
  names_to = "Test"
)

but the output stacks all columns together like so:
  sub_id    mtt_score vat_score time concept cond    day Test    value
   <int>     <int>     <int>   <int> <chr>   <chr> <int> <chr>   <int>
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PreCon      0
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PreMcq      1
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PreFR       0
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PostCon     2
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PostMcq     1
      1        9        26     1    cornea  Comp      1 PostFR      3

I'm not sure how to pivot columns in the pairwise fashion described. Any wisdom would be appreciated.

I'm not sure I understand the final data layout you want. Does this code do what you want?
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.csv("~/R/Play/Dummy.csv")
datl <- pivot_longer(
  dat, 
  cols = c(PreCon, PostCon, PreMcq, PostMcq, PreFR, PostFR), 
  names_to = "Test"
) |> 
  separate_wider_regex("Test", patterns = c(Pre_Post = "Pre|Post", Test = "Con|Mcq|FR"))
datl
#> # A tibble: 36 × 10
#>    sub_id mtt_score vat_score  time concept cond    day Pre_Post Test  value
#>     <int>     <int>     <int> <int> <chr>   <chr> <int> <chr>    <chr> <int>
#>  1      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Pre      Con       0
#>  2      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Post     Con       2
#>  3      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Pre      Mcq       1
#>  4      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Post     Mcq       1
#>  5      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Pre      FR        0
#>  6      1         9        26     1 cornea  C         1 Post     FR        3
#>  7      1         9        26     2 thyroid S         1 Pre      Con       1
#>  8      1         9        26     2 thyroid S         1 Post     Con       2
#>  9      1         9        26     2 thyroid S         1 Pre      Mcq       0
#> 10      1         9        26     2 thyroid S         1 Post     Mcq       0
#> # ℹ 26 more rows
datl |> pivot_wider(names_from = "Test", values_from = "value")
#> # A tibble: 12 × 11
#>    sub_id mtt_score vat_score  time concept    cond    day Pre_Post   Con   Mcq
#>     <int>     <int>     <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <chr>    <int> <int>
#>  1      1         9        26     1 cornea     C         1 Pre          0     1
#>  2      1         9        26     1 cornea     C         1 Post         2     1
#>  3      1         9        26     2 thyroid    S         1 Pre          1     0
#>  4      1         9        26     2 thyroid    S         1 Post         2     0
#>  5      1         9        26     3 cilia      G         2 Pre          0     0
#>  6      1         9        26     3 cilia      G         2 Post         1     0
#>  7      1         9        26     4 histone    C         1 Pre          0     0
#>  8      1         9        26     4 histone    C         1 Post         1     0
#>  9      1         9        26     5 epithelium G         1 Pre          0     0
#> 10      1         9        26     5 epithelium G         1 Post         1     0
#> 11      1         9        26     6 iris       S         1 Pre          4     1
#> 12      1         9        26     6 iris       S         1 Post         3     1
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: FR <int>

Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

This is almost there, but I'd like the "test" variable to instead be split as three columns, called "Con", "Mcq" and "FR".

I edited the answer to have separate columns for the three variables. Note that one colu is  not displayed.

This worked, thanks so much!
